# Outlook addin - ItemChange not being called

Tags: c#, event-handling, vsto, outlook-addin

I am writing an Outlook addin. I need the addin to be notified when any email, in any folder, changes its tags (i.e. when a category is added or removed). I thought of using the ItemChange event ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemsevents_event.itemchange.aspx)), but it is not being fired, no matter what I do to the email (add categories, flags, move it, and so on).

I am aware that you need to create a member variable and set it to MapiFolder.Items, to prevent garbage collection, because events are not called on garbage collected items. But even so, the event is not being called.

My questions are:

1) why is ItemChange not being called in the below code, when in Outlook I try to alter the email in any way (e.g. adding a category)?

2) When exactly is the ItemChange event supposed to be called for a given email?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace TestOutlookAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {

        List<Outlook.Items> mItems = new List<Outlook.Items>();

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            var fo = Application.Session.Folders;
            foreach (Outlook.Folder f in fo)
            {
                var items = f.Items;
                mItems.Add(items);  // prevent garbage collection
                items.ItemChange += Items_ItemChange;
                items.ItemAdd += items_ItemAdd;
                items.ItemRemove += items_ItemRemove;


            }
        }

        void items_ItemRemove()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void Items_ItemChange(object Item) // NOT BEING CALLED <<<<<
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the problem: I was not recurring on subfolders.

```
        var fo = Application.Session.Folders;
        foreach (Outlook.Folder f in fo)
        {

            foreach (Outlook.Folder f2 in f.Folders)
            {

                var items = f2.Items;
                mItems.Add(items);
                items.ItemChange += Items_ItemChange;
                items.ItemAdd += items_ItemAdd;
                items.ItemRemove += items_ItemRemove;

            }
```

or with full recursion:

```
var frontier = new Queue<Folder>();
foreach (Folder f in lSession.Folders)
{
    frontier.Enqueue(f);
}

while (frontier.Any())
{
    var curFolder = frontier.Dequeue();
    curFolder.Items.ItemChange += Items_ItemChange;

    foreach (Folder ch in curFolder.Folders)
    {
        frontier.Enqueue(ch);
    }
}


        }
```

Comment: You are only going 2 levels deep. If you really need this, you need to have a function that processes each folder and call that function recursively for each folder.